# May a Mohel who accepted Shabbos early circumcise a child who turned 8 days old on Friday?

Tags: shabbat, brit-milah

Since the rule that a circumcision pushes off Shabbos is learned from the verse וביום השמיני ימול בשר ערלתו, ויקרא יב ג, from which chaz"l expound "ביום השמיני אפילו בשבת", (שבת קלב ע"א), therefore a circumcision only pushes off shabbos if it is "Bayom Hashmini".
Simply, this means, that Shabbos is the 8th day.
If a baby was born on Friday, then the Yom Hashmini, the 8th day, would on the following Friday.

May a Mohel who accepted shabbos early do a bris on a child who turned 8 days old on Friday? Does that qualify under the rule of 8th day even on Shabbos (since it is now still actually the 8th day), or perhaps not since the eighth day is Friday and not the day of the week called Saturday/Shabbos even if the Mohel accepted the holiness of the holiday of Shabbos early? Perhaps it would be different if the Mohel is the father who is personally obligated here?

Comment: On your last point, if the mohel is the father, there may be more of a reason to forbid. See Ra'avyah (quoted in Tur YD 266) that a father should not circumcise his own child on shabbat, unless there is no other mohel available.

Answer (score 8):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef 1:388:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.388.27?lang=bi):

> מוהל שנקרא למול מילה בזמנה בערב שבת אחר פלג המנחה, והוא כבר קיבל עליו את השבת, ויש שם עוד מוהלים אחרים שלא קיבלו עליהם שבת, יש להסתפק אם מותר לו למול, או שיש להעדיף מוהלים אחרים שלא קיבלו עליהם שבת
>
> A *mohel* who was asked to perform a circumcision on the eighth day which was on a Friday, after *plag hamincha* when he had already accepted *shabbat*, and there are other *mohalim* present who had not yet accepted *shabbat*. The matter is in doubt as to whether he is permitted to perform the circumcision, or whether it is preferable to use another *mohel* who has not accepted *shabbat*.

This would seem to imply (although I didn't find this stated explicitly) that if he is the only *mohel* available then he can certainly perform the circumcision.